# On kronecker product representation of $AA^t$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, orthogonal-matrices, submanifold, kronecker-product

**Proposition**: Prove that orthogonal matrices $\mathrm O_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a regular submanifold of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$.

**Proof**: Denote $f:\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})\to \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R}),A\mapsto AA^t-I_n$

We show that $\forall A \in \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R}) $the image of the tangent map $f_{*{A}}$ is all the $n\times n$ symmetric matrices.

Take a curve $\sigma:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\rightarrow \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R}) $ satisfying $\sigma(0)=A$  then $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}f(\sigma(t))=A^t\dot{\sigma}(0)+(\dot{\sigma}(0))^tA$,which is a symmetric matrix.

Conversely, given any symmetric matrix $B=C+C^t$, let $\sigma (t)=A+(CA^{-1})^t$, it is easy to check that $\sigma (0)=A$ and that $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}f(\sigma(t))=B$. Hence we get $$\operatorname{rank}f=\operatorname{rank}f_{*{A}}$$

By  Regular Value Theorem ,we know that $O_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a regular submanifold of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ with dimension of $\frac{n^2-n}{2}$.

**Question**:I have no problem with the proof. My question here is that is there any other way to calculate the rank of $f$ without using $\operatorname{rank}f=\operatorname{rank}f_{*{A}}$ ? For example, use Kronecker product to explicitly show what $f\in \operatorname{map}(\mathbb{R}^{n^2},\mathbb{R}^{n^2})$ looks like.

**Upgrade**: I think I should restate my question. For example, define $T:GL_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{R}),X\mapsto AX$, then under a basis $T$ has the form $A\otimes I_n$

My question is: does $T':X\mapsto XX^t$ have a similar form?

Comment: The tangent vectors should be [**skew**-symmetric matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2116608/305862)

Comment: See my edits. `\operatorname` is quite a useful command.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are aiming at. The regular value theorem that you want to apply depends on the rank of the derivative of $f$. The map $f$ itself is not linear and hence does not have a well defined rank.

Comment: By rank here I mean the local coordinate representation between a differential manifold and a Euclidean space. And in this way I can get $rankf=rankf_{*A}$